# CPU_ZERO "undefined symbol" using pthread_setaffinity_np in NASM

Tags: linux, assembly, pthreads, x86-64, nasm

I am using the pthreads library in NASM under Ubuntu 18.04.  Thread creation works correctly, but I want to assign each thread to a separate core with  pthread_setaffinity_np.

Following is the section of code I use to initialize threads.  It compiles as written but at run time I get "undefined symbol:  CPU_ZERO."

Using examples from C, I inserted %define _GNU_SOURCE at the top of the program, but I still get the undefined symbol CPU_ZERO error.

```
section .data align=16

; For thread scheduling:
cpuset: times 4 dq 0

section .text

label_0:

mov rdi,ThreadID            ; ThreadCount
mov rsi,pthread_attr_t  ; Thread Attributes
mov rdx,Test_fn         ; Function Pointer
mov rcx,pthread_arg
call pthread_create wrt ..plt

; Set affinity mask
mov rdi,cpuset
call CPU_ZERO wrt ..plt
call pthread_self wrt ..plt
push rax
mov rdi,rax
mov rsi,cpuset
call CPU_SET wrt ..plt
pop rax
mov rdi,rax
mov rsi,32
mov rdx,cpuset
call pthread_setaffinity_np wrt ..plt
; check the result with pthread_getaffinity_np

mov rax,[tcounter]
add rax,8
mov [tcounter],rax
mov rbx,[Number_Of_Cores]
cmp rax,rbx
jl label_0
```

My question is:  how do I use CPU_ZERO and CPU_SET in NASM (or any other assembly language; I can translate to NASM).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The upper case name is a hint, and the man page confirms it: `CPU_ZERO` and `CPU_SET` are macros. You can not call them like functions. You need to look in the headers how they are defined and implement them in assembly.

Comment: I assume the data structure is a bitmap of some size, just zero it with `movups` from a zeroed XMM register.

Comment: Since this only has to run once, you can probably just use memory-destination `bts` to implement `CPU_SET`.  (It's slow with a register source, mostly fine with an immediate source.  Either way it's only 1 instruction.)

Comment: Thanks for that idea @Peter Cordes.  So far this is working out well by substituting my own code for the C macros, but the bitmask for cpuset is the only difficult part.  I will now test it with an xmm register as you suggested, using movups and bts.  When I'm finished I will post all of my code because this question has never been asked before (I searched thoroughly) and others may benefit from my experience.

Comment: My approach to this problem is summarized in my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59776532/reproduce-these-c-types-in-assembly/59870573#59870573.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CPU_ZERO` and `CPU_SET` are C macros, not functions which you can call.

You'll have to roll your own function to perform equivalent zeroing / setting.

Answer (score 2):

Those are CPP macros, not function. You can tell from the all-caps names.  And from the fact [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/CPU_SET.3.html) calls them macros.

As usual, the [notes section](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/CPU_SET.3.html#NOTES) of the man page has details that are useful for asm:

> Since **CPU sets are bit masks allocated in units of long words**, the
>          actual number of CPUs in a dynamically allocated CPU set will be
>          rounded up to the next multiple of `sizeof(unsigned long)`.  An
>          application should consider the contents of these extra bits to be
>          undefined.
>
> Notwithstanding the similarity in the names, note that the constant
>          **`CPU_SETSIZE` indicates the number of CPUs in the `cpu_set_t` data type
>          (thus, it is effectively a count of the bits in the bit mask)**, while
>          the setsize argument of the CPU_*_S() macros is a size in bytes.

On my system (Arch Linux, glibc 2.29-4)

`/usr/include/bits/cpu-set.h` says

```
...
#define __CPU_SETSIZE   1024
#define __NCPUBITS      (8 * sizeof (__cpu_mask))
...
typedef __CPU_MASK_TYPE __cpu_mask;  // ultimately unsigned long via some other headers
...
typedef struct
{
  __cpu_mask __bits[__CPU_SETSIZE / __NCPUBITS];
} cpu_set_t;
```

**So a `cpu_set_t` is 1024 bits = 128 bytes = `times 16 dq 0` or `resq 16`,** at least on my system with that kernel config.

---

`CPU_ZERO` is free in your case; your statically-allocated `cpu_set_t` is statically zero-initialized.  For some reason you put it in `.data` instead of `.bss`, so the executable will have to actually contain those zeros, but same difference.

If you did want to zero one on the stack, for example, `rep stosd` is one easy way, or `xorps xmm0, xmm0` and 8x `movups` stores would also work.

---

Since high performance is not essential (CPU affinity-setting code probably only runs once), **[`bts`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bts) is a very convenient way to set bits in a bitmap (`CPU_SET`)**.  With a memory destination, it takes a bit-index that can go outside the `dword` selected by the addressing mode.  `bts mem, reg` is slow and microcoded (like 10 uops on Skylake), but nice for code size.  `bts mem, imm` is only 3 uops, but `or byte [mem + i/8], 1<<(i%8)` is only 2 uops.

`or` also lets you set more than 1 bit at once, **or more simply just `mov` store some bytes that contain the desired pattern of zeros and ones.**

But TL:DR: it's just a bitmap, manipulate it however you like using asm, or even statically initialize it with non-zero values.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to solving this problem is summarized in my answer at [Reproduce these C types in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59776532/reproduce-these-c-types-in-assembly/59870573#59870573).